# 0x800a139e - SyntaxError - Telerik RadGrid

Tags: telerik

i'm trying to execute one jquery function, but it giver me an error and i don't know what is going on. It is really kiling me. I don't know what else i can do.

If someone know's how to fix it, please help me.

error:
Exception was thrown at line 5263, column 7 in localhost:8538/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setpager();
        });

        function setpager() {
            $("#grdTeste .rgPagerCell:first").find('div').not(".rgInfoPart").css('display', 'none');
            $("#grdTeste .rgPagerCell:last").find('.rgInfoPart').css('display', 'none');
        }
    </script>
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %></h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" valign="bottom" height="25">
                              <font id="tituloTela" style="padding-left:6px"> Feriados </font>
                            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="setpager();"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdTeste" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="0" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" GridLines="None" PageSize="5" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" >
        <ExportSettings>
            <Pdf PageWidth="">
            </Pdf>

        </ExportSettings>
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="COD_FERIADO" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" CommandItemDisplay="Top" >
            <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Adicionar Novo Registro" RefreshText="Atualizar"/>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DATA" FilterControlAltText="Filter DATA column" HeaderText="DATA" SortExpression="DATA" UniqueName="DATA">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NOME" FilterControlAltText="Filter NOME column" HeaderText="NOME" SortExpression="NOME" UniqueName="NOME">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="COD_FERIADO" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter COD_FERIADO column" HeaderText="COD_FERIADO" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="COD_FERIADO" UniqueName="COD_FERIADO">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column"></EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
        <PagerStyle Position="TopAndBottom" AlwaysVisible="true"/>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StringConexao %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM feriados WHERE (COD_FERIADO = @COD_FERIADO)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DATA, NOME, COD_FERIADO FROM feriados" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE feriados SET NOME = @NOME, DATA = @DATA WHERE (COD_FERIADO = @COD_FERIADO)" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO feriados VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_FERIADO_NOVA, @DATA, @NOME)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="COD_FERIADO" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="DATA" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NOME" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="NOME" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DATA" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="COD_FERIADO" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: where is ur control with id="grdTeste" and with class="rgPagerCell"

Comment: Now the code is correct, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your are using plain javascript for finding radgrid(telerik controls).

The javascript used for telerik contols is different than the normal javascript for html contols:

To find radgrid with `id="grdTeste"`:

```
var grdTeste=$find("<%=grdTeste.ClientID%>");  //find radgrid
```

This will help you to work with radgrid on client side:

**[Working with Radgrid on client side](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html)**